# Ignoring vertices of a meshgrid outside UV map

Tags: mesh, uv, geometry-nodes, boolean-modifier

What I want to do is to make field of holes in a curved mesh. Using geometry nodes I make a UV map of the mesh that is supposed to have holes in it. Then I make a meshgrid of various size and number of vertices so I can change the density of holes easily. Then I "fit" the mesh on the UV map and put instances on vertices of the meshgrid and align the instances. Then using Boolean difference I make holes in the mesh using these instances. Geometry nodes look like this.
[image]

It works quite well. The only problem is that the vertices of meshgrid that are outside the UV map transfer to the nearest face so on the edge of mesh there are many vertices I would like to ignore or delete because it makes mess. It looks like this.
[image]

As you can see it works but the edges are gathering the points outside the UV map and it makes this mess. Do you have any idea how to ignore or delete these vertices ? I don't want to do it manually. Thank you for any idea.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the *Geometry proximity* node to get the distance between UV coordinate and spawned cylinder. And use *selection* input socket to prevent spawning cylinder if this distance is lager than 0

[image]

Comment: Works like charm ! Thank you very much !